# App can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

Tags: java, macos

I wrote a java application whit my windows Pc. When i try the same application on a MAC Pc i had this error: "can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer".

I tried looking for this problem on Google and I read that this option can be
disable, but i dont wanna do it. How can i fix this problem? Should I buy a licence or somethink like that?

Comment: open your settings and go to security. Then, in General, you'll see a warning and you have to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7488189) on the Apple Support forum, it appears that you must enroll in the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/) to become an identified developer. This will get you a Developer ID certificate from Apple that will cause your app to be recognized by Gatekeeper as having come from an identified developer.

Comment: He's having this problem on a Windows PC, not MacOS.

Comment: So if i register myself on https://developer.apple.com/ i get a Developer ID. But can i identified my program whitout publich that? And how? The program is for me and some my friend i don't wanna publish in the apple store

Comment: You will also get a certificate which can be used to code sign your app. This will cause the app to be recognized as being from an identified developer even though it didn't come from the Apple App Store. Here is some [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing/) on that process

Comment: I read the documentation, but that's about Xcode. How can i sign in java?
BTW realy thanks you for the help